# Loop though files in a Folder on Mac OS X - VBA Excel 2011

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to loop through files in a folder on Mac OS X using VBA Excel 2011. I tried the following code, but it does not work.

```
Sub ListAllFilesInDir()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strPath1 As String

    strPath1 = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    MsgBox strPath1
    strFile = Dir(strPath1)
    MsgBox strFile
    strFile = Dir()
    MsgBox strFile
    strFile = Dir()
    MsgBox strFile
End Sub
```

I get the name of the active workbook when the program reaches the first `MsgBox strFile`. I read somewhere that using `Dir` without an argument results in the next file in the folder. But that does not work for me. I get an empty message box for the second `MsgBox strFile` command and an error (Runtime error 5: Invalid Procedure call or argument" for the third `MsgBox strFile` command. I have 4 files in the folder that I am trying to loop through.

Also, what would I do to list only ".xslx" files

Comment: If you are still looking for an answer, please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045474/dir-function-not-working-in-mac-excel-2011-vba

Answer (score -4):

[Here's a link](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php) to a description of the dir() function.  Your issue is that dir(strPath1) will set the dir function to return all instances of that EXACT filename in that path, which is only ever going to be a single file.  If you'd like all files ending in ".xlsx" try:

```
dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & application.PathSeparator & "*.xlsx")
```

Also, if you have an arbitrary number of files you want to loop through try the following code.  It works becuase dir returns an empty string after it's returned the last file:

```
Sub WorkWithFiles()
    Const PATH = "C:\"

    Dim file As String

    file = Dir(PATH & Application.PathSeparator & "*.xlsx")
    Do Until file = ""
        'Run some code on the file in the file variable
        Debug.Print file
        'Then get the next file
        file = Dir("")
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: wildcards ( `*` ) don't work on Mac like this. see the link Siddharth gives above.