# Dir() function not working in Mac Excel 2011 VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Hi I am trying to list all the files in a subdirectory of where the Excel workbook is residing in. For some reason, the code cannot execute beyond the Dir function. Can anyone please advise? Thank you!

```
Sub ListFiles()

    ActiveSheet.Name = "temp"

    Dim MyDir As String
    'Declare the variables
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim r As Long

    MyDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path 'current path where workbook is
    strPath = MyDir & ":Current:" 'files within "Current" folder subdir, I am using Mac Excel 2011

    'Insert the headers in Columns A, B, and C
    Cells(1, "A").Value = "FileName"
    Cells(1, "B").Value = "Size"
    Cells(1, "C").Value = "Date/Time"

    'Find the next available row
    r = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Get the first file from the folder
            'Note: macro stops working here
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv", vbNormal)

    'Loop through each file in the folder
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0

        'List the name, size, and date/time of the current file
        Cells(r, 1).Value = strFile
        Cells(r, 2).Value = FileLen(strPath & strFile)
        Cells(r, 3).Value = FileDateTime(strPath & strFile)

        'Determine the next row
        r = r + 1

        'Get the next file from the folder
        strFile = Dir

    Loop

    'Change the width of the columns to achieve the best fit
    Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: What does "cannot execute" mean exactly? Is there an error message? What exactly is the content of `strPath` when execution stops stops?

Answer (score 19):

Gianna, you cannot use `DIR` like that in VBA-EXCEL 2011. I mean the wildcards are not supported. You have to use MACID for this purpose.

See this code sample (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    MyDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    strPath = MyDir & ":"

    strFile = Dir(strPath, MacID("TEXT"))

    'Loop through each file in the folder
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        If Right(strFile, 3) = "csv" Then
            Debug.Print strFile
        End If

        strFile = Dir    
    Loop
End Sub
```

See this link for more details on MACID

**Topic: MacID Function**

**Link**: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/macid-function-HA001228879.aspx

**EDIT:**

In case that link ever dies which I doubt, here is an extract.

> > > > **MacID Function**
> > > >
> > > > Used on the Macintosh to convert a 4-character constant to a value that may be used by Dir, Kill, Shell, and AppActivate.
> > > >
> > > > **Syntax**
> > > >
> > > > MacID(constant)
> > > >
> > > > The required constant argument consists of 4 characters used to specify a resource type, file type, application signature, or Apple Event, for example, TEXT, OBIN, "XLS5" for Excel files ("XLS8" for Excel 97), Microsoft Word uses "W6BN" ("W8BN" for Word 97), and so on.
> > > >
> > > > **Remarks**
> > > >
> > > > MacID is used with Dir and Kill to specify a Macintosh file type. Since the Macintosh does not support * and ? as wildcards, you can use a four-character constant instead to identify groups of files. For example, the following statement returns TEXT type files from the current folder:
> > > >
> > > > Dir("SomePath", MacID("TEXT"))
> > > >
> > > > MacID is used with Shell and AppActivate to specify an application using the application's unique signature.

HTH

Comment: An issue to be aware of here is that the returned file paths are shortened to fit a 31-character limit (the filename limit from the pre-OS X HFS file system).  The shortening function keeps the file extension but alters the chars before it, similar to short path names for files on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Dir(outputFileName) <> "" Then
Dim ans
ans = MsgBox("File already exists.Do you wish to continue(the previous file will be    deleted)?", vbYesNo)
If ans = vbNo Then
Exit Sub
Else
Kill outputFileName
End If
End If

For listitem = 0 To List6.ListCount() - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the answer above, it worked for me when I took out the "TEXT" in MacID:

```
Sub LoopThruFiles()

    Dim mydir As String
    Dim foldercount As Integer
    Dim Subjectnum As String
    Dim strpath As String
    Dim strfile As String

    ChDir "HD:Main Folder:"
    mydir = "HD:Main Folder:"
    SecondaryFolder = "Folder 01:"
    strpath = mydir & SecondaryFolder

    strfile = Dir(strpath)

    'Loop through each file in the folder
    Do While Len(strfile) > 0
     If Right(strfile, 3) = "cef" Then
        MsgBox (strfile)
        End If
        strfile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```