# ThisWorkbook.Path for Mac returns (error 68)

Tags: macos, excel, vba

I downloaded a spreadsheet which seems to be originally written for windows.  The file is here     http://www.automateexcel.com/2004/12/15/create_an_rss_feed_with_excel/.

For line RssLocation = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FeedSheet.Cells(5, 2).Value

I have replaced "\" with with "/user/desktop/rsscreate.xlsm" but I still get the error. 
I have also, tried  "& Application.PathSeparator &" but still the error.

Any suggestions?

The code for the macro is below.

---

```
Sub WriteRss()
Dim X As Long
Dim FeedSheet As Worksheet

Dim RssLocation As String
Dim DomainName As String
Dim DomainDescription As String
Dim DomainTitle As String

    'Change the word "Sheet1" to the tabname of
    'the sheet where you keep your feeds list
    Set FeedSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Your domain name(include the http://)
    DomainName = FeedSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value

    'Your Site's Title
    DomainTitle = FeedSheet.Cells(3, 2).Value

    'Your Site's Description
    DomainDescription = FeedSheet.Cells(4, 2).Value

    'Location to write file, defaults to workbook directory
    RssLocation = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FeedSheet.Cells(5, 2).Value

    'Kill the file if it already exists
    If Len(Dir(RssLocation)) > 0 Then
        Kill RssLocation
    End If

    Open RssLocation For Append As #1
    Print #1, "<?xml version=""1.0""" & " encoding=""iso-8859-1""?>"
    Print #1, "<rss version=" & """" & "2.0" & """" & _
              " xmlns:content = ""http:" & _
              "//purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"">"
    Print #1, "    <channel>"
    Print #1, "    <title>" & DomainTitle & "</title>"
    Print #1, "    <link>" & DomainName & "</link>"
    Print #1, "    <description>" & DomainDescription & "</description>"
    Print #1, "    <language>en-us</language>"

    'Loop through sheet specified
    'Start @ row 2
    'ColumnA=Title, ColumnB=Link, ColumnC=Description

    For X = 9 To FeedSheet.Range("A" & FeedSheet.Rows.Count) _
        .End(xlUp).Row
        Print #1, "    <item>"
        Print #1, "      <title>" & FeedSheet.Cells(X, 1).Value & _
                  "</title>"
        Print #1, "      <link>" & FeedSheet.Cells(X, 2).Value & _
                  "</link>"
        Print #1, "<description>"
        Print #1, "<![CDATA["
        Print #1, FeedSheet.Cells(X, 3).Value
        Print #1, "  ]]> "
        Print #1, "</description>"
        Print #1, "    </item>"
    Next

    Print #1, "  </channel>"
    Print #1, "</rss>"
    Close #1
MsgBox "Your new RSS feed can be found here: " & RssLocation
End Sub

Sub InsertNew()
    Range("A9:C17").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A10:C18").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A18:C18").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A9:C9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** adding the following from the Answers section.

I tried the code in previous answer. I'm still getting error at line `If Len(Dir(RssLocation)) > 0`

Any suggestions on how can use MacId and ThisWorkbook.Path instead of Applcaton.PathSeparator?. Siddharth your thoughts?

Comment: see [link1.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271915/thisworkbook-path-for-mac) [link2.MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264329%28v=office.14%29.aspx) [link3.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045474/dir-function-not-working-in-mac-excel-2011-vba)

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045474/dir-function-not-working-in-mac-excel-2011-vba

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Untested)

```
RssLocation = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FeedSheet.Cells(5, 2).Value
RssLocation = Replace(RssLocation ,"\", Application.PathSeparator)
'Debug.Print RssLocation
```

Comment: I tried the code but same error at line If Len(Dir(RssLocation)) > 0 Then. Seems I'm not getting the correct path.

Considering I am on a Macintosh is "\" a possible issue?

Comment: uncomment the line `Debug.Print RssLocation` an see what is the value of `RssLocation`? We are not using `\`. If you see in the above code, "\" is being replaced by the `Application.PathSeparator`