# Dir function does not work in Excel 2011 for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am learning VBA and I am stuck at the following code:

```
1 Sub openwb()
2 Dim myfile As String, mypath As String
3 mypath = "SolidHD:Users:ls:Desktop:untitled:"
4 myfile = Dir(mypath & "*.xls*")
5 Do While myfile <> ""
6 Workbooks.Open "mypath & myfile"
7 myfile = Dir()
8 Loop
9 End Sub
```

I get the following error:Runtime Error 68 Device Unavailable. The debug function highlights line 4.
I've searched through the Internet without joy... This is very frustrating... I cannot understand what's wrong.

Comment: Please confirm if the above link worked for you. If it did then we can close this question as a duplicate or you can delete this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dir() function not working in Mac Excel 2011 VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045474/dir-function-not-working-in-mac-excel-2011-vba)

Comment: Yes, it works. Sorry... didn't see the post. Many thanks!!!