# Converting XML files to Excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I found the code below but I don't know VBA -- I get a compile error on the first line:

```
Sub xmltoxl()
Dim f As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim s As Integer

f = Dir("C:\Users\Kanye\Downloads\fwcommoncartridgesforsegtitles\zipped\basicLTILinks" & "\*.xml")
s = 0

Do While Len(f) > 0
    s = s + 1
    Set wbk = Workbooks.OpenXML("C:\Users\Kanye\Downloads\fwcommoncartridgesforsegtitles\zipped" & "\" & f)
wbk.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Kanye\Downloads\fwcommoncartridgesforsegtitles\zipped\" & s & ".xls"
wbk.Close False
f = Dir()
Loop
```

My directory for my .xlsm file:
C:\Users\Kanye\Downloads\fwcommoncartridgesforsegtitles\Texas_Gr6_IScience_2015

My directory for my .xml files:
C:\Users\Kanye\Downloads\fwcommoncartridgesforsegtitles\Texas_Gr6_IScience_2015\basicLTILinks

Am I putting these in the right places?

I'd like it so that the all the XML files are pulled into a single CSV

Comment: You need an `End Sub` at the very end to close "Sub xmltoxl()". An `Option Explicit` at the top of the module is also strongly advised

Comment: Added but now I get an error "Run-time error '68'.  Device unavailable."  Running this on a Mac - Excel 11'

Comment: A Windows path like "C:\Users\Kanye..." is not going to make any sense on a Mac. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10045474/2127508) for how to use Dir on a Mac

Comment: Thanks it works now but the files it returns give this error upon opening: http://imgur.com/SiyiGag .. any clue why it's corrupted?

Comment: [Workbook.SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185(v=office.15).aspx) can take a [FileFormat parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) so try using either the "xlCSV" or "xlCSVMac" options - `wbk.SaveAs yourFilenameHere, xlCSV` or `wbk.SaveAs yourFilenameHere, xlCSVMac` (I don't have access to a Mac to check this directly, though)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very sure what you mean with that can you tell me the error. And Here Are Some Nice Resources

Click [here](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm" Code Cleaner")  for Code Cleaner

Click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications"Wikipedia) for a Wikipedia