# Excel 2011 on Mac - Macro - FileCopy filename length limit

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm using the macro below to copy images from folder "Images" based on image code from column C to newly created folders, named by content of column A. The macro works without any issues on Windows but it looks like there is a limit of 25 characters in image filename with Mac Excel. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
Sub copy into individual folder()
Sheets(1).Select
Dim R As Range
Dim RootFolder As String
RootFolder = ""  '<<< CHANGE 1
For Each R In Range("A4:A500") '<<< CHANGE 2
    If Len(R.Text) > 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path
        MkDir ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & Left(R.Text, 6)
        Dim fn As String
        myDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "IMAGES" '<- alter here
        'Debug.Print "Image directory " & myDir
        ChDir myDir
        newFolder = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & Left(R.Text, 6) '<- alter here
        'Debug.Print "Image code: " & Range("C" & R.Row).Text
        Search = myDir & Application.PathSeparator & "*" & Trim(Range("C" & R.Row).Text) & "*"
        found = 0
        fn = Dir("")
        Do While fn <> ""
            If InStr(fn, Range("C" & R.Row).Text) Then
                'Debug.Print "Copying file " & fn & " to " & newFolder
                'Debug.Print myDir & Application.PathSeparator & fn
                'Debug.Print newFolder & Application.PathSeparator & fn
                FileCopy myDir & Application.PathSeparator & fn, newFolder & Application.PathSeparator & fn
                found = 1
            End If
            fn = Dir
            'Debug.Print "File in images folder: " & fn
            'Debug.Print fn
        Loop
        If found = 0 Then
            R.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End If
Next R
End Sub
```

Comment: See [Dir() function not working in Mac Excel 2011 VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045474/dir-function-not-working-in-mac-excel-2011-vba) for a few special things you need to get the [Dir function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779.aspx) working correctly on a MAC. Also, there are compiler directives that identify the MAC environment and can offer two solutions in one procedure.

Comment: Should have mentioned earlier that I'm not really familiar with vba, i didnt write this macro, im just a curious "user". Did you meant "*" in my Search would not work properly on Mac? Beacuse Dir seems to ok with quoted links?

Comment: No, I mean you need to use MACID in your Dir function and possibly reshape the original search string.

Comment: You are probably right and I think that's a little bit above my "skills", I'll either stick to Windows for this procedure or get professional to sort it out for me, cheers for your time anyway!