# Get name and path of opened Workbook using VBA

Tags: vba

I just wanted to ask how I get the *name* and *path* of the actual opened Workbook with VBA?

I tried it as captured in the snippet below but keep getting a compiler error.

My document-type is `.docm`.

What am I doing wrong?

My code snippet:

```
Sub TestFileOpened()
Dim strPath As String, strPathAndName As String

    strPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
    strPathAndName = strPath & Application.ThisWorkbook.Name
    MsgBox strPathAndName 

    ' Test to see if the file is open.
    If IsFileOpen(strPathAndName) Then ....
```

Comment: `ThisWorkBook` is an Excel object! Are you working in Word?

Comment: Thank you that was my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the location of the open word document, try the below:

```
Sub TestFileOpened()
Dim strPath As String, strPathAndName As String

    strPath = ThisDocument.Path
    strPathAndName = strPath & "\" & ThisDocument.Name
    MsgBox strPathAndName 

    ' Test to see if the file is open.
    If IsFileOpen(strPathAndName) Then ....
```

(Note not to forget to add the backslash between file path and name)

Comment: Thank you for that!

Comment: I have an other question maybe you can help me....
I wanted to use this code with a mac but if i only replace the "\" with ":" there is an error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @T.Els I dont often program vba on a mac, but you could see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045474/dir-function-not-working-in-mac-excel-2011-vba

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you are trying to use some Excel code from Word, so first you need to get a hold on Excel App :

```
Dim oExcel as Excel.Application
Dim wB as Excel.WorkBook
Dim strPath As String
Dim strPathAndName As String


On Error Resume Next
Set oExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0


Set wB = oExcel.Workbooks(1)
strPath = wB.Path
strPathAndName = strPath & "\" & wB.Name
MsgBox strPathAndName 

' Test to see if the file is open.
If IsFileOpen(strPathAndName) Then ....
```