# Dir() in Excel for Mac 2016 causes crash

Tags: excel, macos, excel-2016

I am trying to iterate through files using Dir, and I understand that it works differently on Mac than windows.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045474/dir-function-not-working-in-mac-excel-2011-vba) has been helpful, but I have been unable to implement the solution suggested. The first call to Dir successfully returns a desired filename, but the second call crashes excel. I would like to implement a pattern like this:

```
Sub printFileNames()
  Dim path as String
  Dim fileName as String
  path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/SUBFOLDER/"
  fileName = Dir(path, MacID("XLSX"))
  While fileName <> ""
    MsgBox fileName
    fileName = Dir 'This CRASHES EXCEL
  Wend
End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot of the error message, upon crash:[image]

Is this a known bug? Am I using Dir incorrectly for the Mac version of Excel 2016?

**EDIT:**
I have also tried using this exact solution, posted in the above linked question:

```
Sub Sample()
MyDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path
strPath = MyDir & ":SUBFOLDER:"

strFile = Dir(strPath, MacID("TEXT"))

'Loop through each file in the folder
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    If Right(strFile, 3) = "csv" Then
        Debug.Print strFile
    End If

    strFile = Dir    
Loop
End Sub
```

But this gives a "File Not Found" error, even though there are both .csv, .txt, and .xlsx files in the specified folder. Using:`/SUBFOLDER/` instead of `:SUBFOLDER:` prints the appropriate file name for the first loop, but crashes upon calling `strFile = Dir`

Comment: Try `path = ThisWorkbook.Path & ":SUBFOLDER:"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045474/dir-function-not-working-in-mac-excel-2011-vba/38042805 Also Try `MacID("TEXT")`

Comment: Thank you for your (immediate) response. I have tried replacing the '/'s with ':'s e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Path & ":SUBFOLDER:"`, and this causes a file not found error when calling Dir for the first time, whereas using: `ThisWorkbook.Path & "/SUBFOLDER/"` does return the name of the first file in the subfolder. (Though it then crashes upon getting to the second Dir call). I have also Tried `MacID("TEXT")` with both colons (:) and slashes (/) as folder delimiters, but this also threw a no file found error, while `MacID("XLSX")` returns the file name, the first time

Comment: Did you see my 2nd comment?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my response to refer to my attempts to implement these changes, but neither has returned any files (though doing so did not crash)

Answer (score 1):

Use Ron de Bruin's macscript:

https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac013.htm
Loop through Files in Folder on a Mac (Dir for Mac Excel)