# VBA Get sub-directories on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I need to return a list of sub-directories for a given folder for a Mac. I have been unsuccessful with my attempts at using Dir or MacScript, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Dir has a special argument for macos.

Comment: On a Mac, the function only returned a "." directory and system files, with or without attributes (tried using vbDirectory).

Answer (score 0):

`Dir` does not have the same support on Mac as it does on Windows. Use Ron de Bruin's resources for VBA in Excel for Mac. [Loop through Files in Folder on a Mac (Dir for Mac Excel)](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac013.htm)

Also see:

Related StackOverflow question for [Excel 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045474/dir-function-not-working-in-mac-excel-2011-vba)

Related StackOverflor question for [Excel 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784364/dir-in-excel-for-mac-2016-causes-crash?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Ron de Bruin link has moved to https://macexcel.com/examples/filesandfolders/loopthroughfiles/

Answer (score 0):

Use:
VBA.Dir("folder",vbDirectory)
This will give you all files and folders.
Store the results in an array, concatenation "folder" with the result of VBA.Dir()...

Then you loop through the array, using dir to check if there's files within each folder ...

Its far from perfect, because you cannot use Dir recursively, so you'd get only first level subfolders. But worked fine for me.