# Excel VBA on mac - Make Directory, Hyperlink

Tags: vba, macos, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a schedule mapper with Excel.
It works great so far but only on windows.
Will there be any solution for the below codes to work on Mac OS as well?

```
Sub MakeFolders()
   ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).Select
   Dim Rng As Range
   Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer
   Set Rng = Selection
   maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
   maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count

   For c = 1 To maxCols
      r = 1
      Do While r <= maxRows
         If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c))
            On Error Resume Next
         End If
         r = r + 1
      Loop
   Next c
End Sub
```

Below is the hyperlink to a folder that doesn't work on Mac as well.

*B16 = 14

```
HYPERLINK=("..\test\"&B16,"GO")
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Well, to start you should learn OS basics. :-) On *nix based operating systems, the forward slash is the path separator. The backslash is Windows.

Comment: the Mac version of Excel is not nearly as powerful as the Windows version, and the VBA is especially weak on the mac.  I use a Windows emulator (parallels or vmware) just so that I can have the Windows versions of Excel, Word, and PowerPoint. In my opinion, it's deceptive to even call the Mac versions by the same names. But if you really want to try to use mac versions for VBA, here is a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045474/dir-function-not-working-in-mac-excel-2011-vba

Comment: Right.. I didn't think about path separators.
Now I'm sure I should make it on web not in excel program.
Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting.  Definitely worth a read.

https://www.howtogeek.com/181774/why-windows-uses-backslashes-and-everything-else-uses-forward-slashes/