# Wildcards Not Working on Excel 15 VBA Dir()

Tags: vba, excel, wildcard

I've been trying to do something REALLY simple here but, for whatever the reason, it's not working.

All that I'm trying to do is to get all the .txt files from a specific directory using a wildcard.

Here is the full code that I'm using:

```
Sub RenameFiles()

    'Variables Declaration
    Dim vSpreadsheetPath As String
    Dim vFolderName As String
    Dim vFilesPath As String
    Dim vFile As String
    Dim vRow As Long
    Dim vFilter As String

    'Getting the vFile path
    vSpreadsheetPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    vFolderName = "COMBINED FOLDER"
    vFilter = "*.txt"
    vFilesPath = vSpreadsheetPath & Application.PathSeparator & vFolderName & Application.PathSeparator

    vFile = Dir(vFilesPath & vFilter)
    MsgBox (vFile)

End Sub
```

But nothing shows in the result.

The weirdest thing is:
If I use

```
file = Dir(vFilesPath & "filename.txt")
```

It works

But if I try to use any Wildcard, like the one bellow, it doesn't.

```
file = Dir(vFilesPath & "filename.t*")
```

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: `vFilesPath` or `FilesPath`?  Your code sample and your description use two different names.

Comment: if you add a line `MsgBox vFilesPath`, does it list the correct folder?  (Also note that if the workbook is not yet saved then `ActiveWorkbook.Path` returns nothing.

Comment: Sorry about the sample/description, it was a typo here.

Comment: Yes, if I MsgBox vFilesPath, it shows the full path. (The workbook is already saved as well).

Comment: By the way, not sure if this is relevant, but I'm using Excel for Mac OS.

Comment: Can you give an example of what Dir(vFilesPath & "filename.txt") returns when it "works"?

Comment: It is relevant that you're on a Mac since Mac's don't use wildcards like windows.  See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10046053/8112776  -- I think that link is only partly relevant to the issue; I'm not a Mac user but I know they do handle file searches differently.

Comment: Thanks, Ashleedawg. That was indeed the problem. Do you mind posting that as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.  (Posted, thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

It *is* relevant that you're on a Mac since Mac's don't use wildcards like Windows.

You'll need a different approach or a new (re-worded) question for more information about handling the Mac file system with VBA.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10046053/8112776) should help get you started.

<sub>(Posted as an answer by O.P. request.)  **:-)**</sub>