# Excel VBA Dir wildcard command not finding files

Tags: excel, vba, macos

When running the following program, I encounter 'Run-time error '53': File Not Found'.

I've double checked the path, and the files do exist.

```
Sub OpenFiles()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String

MyFolder = "/Users/my_name/desktop/excel_files"

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "/*.xl??")

Do While MyFile <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "/" & MyFile

MyFile = Dir()

Loop

End Sub
```

I am using Excel for Mac 2017.

Comment: By default Dir will not find read-only, system, or hidden files. Do you have permission to write to the files in question?

Comment: Yes, I have read and write access to files in question

Comment: what line is throwing that error?

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045474/dir-function-not-working-in-mac-excel-2011-vba

Comment: @DisplayName Line 5, the line with the Dir command

Comment: does it error out at the first iteration?

Comment: @DisplayName Yes

Comment: @TimWilliams The MacID("TEXT") suggestion from the top answer didn't work either.    Still erroring out at Dir

Comment: what if you try `MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "/*.xl*")`?

Comment: Easiest solution might be to list all files with no filter, then filter them in your loop.

Comment: @hgst, please give some news/feedback, it could help other people

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac013.htm

Comment: I don't have Excel for Mac, but according to the documentation, `DIR` on a Mac cannot use wild cards, since `*` and `?` can be used in the filenames.  See the reference posted by @TimWilliams.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045474/dir-function-not-working-in-mac-excel-2011-vba

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dir() function not working in Mac Excel 2011 VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045474/dir-function-not-working-in-mac-excel-2011-vba)