# Word for Mac - Error while calling Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open runtime error -2146959355 (80080005)

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word

I am trying to open an Excel file in Word to read the values of some cells and do some magic to a new file in word.

A thing that I did many times using Microsoft Windows. Now that I'm unable to use Windows and I have to use my private computer I am facing some issues to use the files that I wrote on my Mac.

I am using the same version on both O.Ss.: Office Word 2016 but I am getting an error when I run the macro in my mac.

I am getting a

> Runtime-Error with code -2146959355 (80080005).

The code is huge but I tried stripping down to find the error. Needless to say that I've reached the point that stripping more is equals to removing the macro. So, this is the code that is giving me the error. And I can't understand the reason.

```
Sub AutoOpen()

    Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim excelFile As String
    excelFile = ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "file.xlsx"

    If (Dir(excelFile) <> "") Then
        Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelFile)
        exWb.Close
    Else
        MsgBox ("File not found")
    End If
End Sub
```

The error is referring to the `Set` of `exWb`

This same code is working in Windows

Comment: What does `Debug.Print excelFile` return? Not sure, but [possibly helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045474/dir-function-not-working-in-mac-excel-2011-vba).

Comment: That variable contains the correct path: `/Volumes/USB/file.xlsx`(I used to check with `MsgBox`)

Comment: So if you drop the `Dir` completely the file opens?

Comment: nope. I've also tried removing the If-Else block... (and prior of that changing the file name and the Else part was called correctly)

Comment: AFAIK you need to use AppleScript for this. It’s something to do with sandboxing.

Comment: ^^ Agree. Office VBA can access only a limited number of folders (i.e. "sandboxing"). I'm only a casual Mac user/dev so I don't have this memorized, but if you research a bit you should be able to find the information on the Internet. As I recall, it's a folder "beneath" an Office folder...

Comment: if that's true, that's the silliest thing that microsoft or apple could have done.........

Comment: The location accessible to VBA is ~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/. (See https://macadmins.software/docs/UserContentIn2016.pdf) This is just one a number of issues you will face as Word for Mac is missing some functionality, e.g. building blocks. And additional libraries you may rely on in Windows will obvs be missing, e.g. XML, scripting. You may also find this link helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/office-mac

Comment: I think that can be the problem, I solved with a virtualbox and W10 installation........... rude but I need to go on working

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that on Mac, creating new COM objects via New or CreateObject is currently broken. Or at least, it is broken for some users with fresh installations of Mac OS and Office.

If you can pin your code down a little more, I think you will see that this error occurs in the first executable line after "Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application".

This problem has been reported to Microsoft on several occasions over several years, but there has been no obvious response. My guess is that either their dev. team has made historic changes to their Mac OS configuration that they have forgotten about that means they don't encounter this problem, or that the people who had expertise in working with COM on Mac have left and Microsoft is stalling until they can recover some relevant expertise.

There does not really seem to be any obvious Microsoft documentation about it.

---

Update.

In v. 16.34 of Mac Word, things seem to have changed a bit.

GetObject is still useless.

But if you do

```
Dim app as Object
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

app is no longer Nothing. Unfortunately, if you do

typename(app)

you get "WorkBook" which means that the code is still not returning the right kind of object.

But here, I can at least now do something like

```
If UCase(Typename(app)) = "WORKBOOK" Then
  Set app = App.Application
End If
```

Comment: I agree that COM automation is broken (at least in some circumstances). However I have also encountered the problem of sand-boxing (as mentioned in comments). As the OP has not responded to either suggestion, it's difficult to know which the primary issue is. This contribution can stand on its own, as an Answer even though it may turn out to not be "the answer"; but the remarks I edited out don't belong on the site.

Comment: I don't think that is the case, yes it can be broken but the problem was not on creating the new object because if I used a check with "Dim" without having the file it was opening the alert box correctly, even after having initialized the new object.
the problem was in opening the file. As one of the last comment to my question say

Comment: @Gianmarco: I wasn't able to comment before, but you are probably right. A recent update may have changed things - see my updated text.

Answer (score 1):

Not a Mac user so can't test this directly.  According to Microsoft, you need to grant permission to the files to be opened because the files are "external" to the Office application which runs in a sandbox.  See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/office-mac/grantaccesstomultiplefiles