# Cause of Error object variable or with block variable not set error 91 when extracting text from excel to word

Tags: excel, vba, object, ms-word

I have two files.

**MWB 5x7 Card Draft - Final:**
added a content control field at top right corner where the Random phrase will be placed.

1. having macro named "Extract_Random_Phrases_from_XL()"
2. added Microsoft Excel object library to it already.

**Oblique Strategies:**
list of phrase.

Now when I run the following code it causes runtime error
`"object variable or with block variable not set error 91"`

[image]

at

[image]

don't know how to set this code. please help

```
Sub Extract_Random_Phrases_from_XL()

Dim oXL As Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim oRng As Excel.Range
Dim ExcelWasNotRunning As Boolean
Dim WorkbookToWorkOn As String

''''''''''Specify the workbook to get Random Phrases'''''''''''''''
WorkbookToWorkOn = ActiveDocument.Path & "\Oblique Strategies.xlsx"

'If Excel is running, get a handle on it; otherwise start a new instance of Excel
On Error Resume Next
Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err Then
   ExcelWasNotRunning = True
   Set oXL = New Excel.Application
End If

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

'Open the workbook
Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=WorkbookToWorkOn)
    
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Range.Text = oWB.Worksheets("Oblique Strategies").Range("C2").Value
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

If ExcelWasNotRunning Then
  oWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
End If

'Make sure you release object references.
Set oRng = Nothing
Set oSheet = Nothing
Set oWB = Nothing
Set oXL = Nothing

    
Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
   MsgBox WorkbookToWorkOn & " caused a problem. " & Err.Description, vbCritical, _
           "Error: " & Err.Number
   If ExcelWasNotRunning Then
       oXL.Quit ''''' error causing line
   End If

End Sub
```

Where I am doing it wrong?
if there is another method to do that task please suggest?
if my code have extra line please mention that too?

Comment: Looks like your code is failing to create an excel instance.  Try adding `On Error Goto 0` immediately after the `GetObject` line, and change your next line to `If oXL Is nothing Then`

Comment: @TimWilliams I have checked my code on window OS it is working fine but causing `error 91` on `MAC OS`.

Comment: Your filepath to the Word document is wrong. Macs don't use \ as the separator.

Comment: Maybe the same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791807/word-for-mac-error-while-calling-excel-application-workbooks-open-runtime-erro   Sorry- can't follow up since I'm not a Mac user.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong, and there's a lot of indirect evidence that the Office COM is broken on Mac.  My code is quite similar to yours and suffers exactly the same problem on Mac.  I have tried variations of opening an XLSM file with Excel.Application object, Excel.Workbook object, and the Workbook object.  It just doesn't work.  Contrary to other responses, the XL object is being created properly when one isn't available, or "gotten" via GETOBJECT properly as I can see it in the Windows task manager just fine:

```
Dim XL As Excel.Application
Dim WB As String: WB = "RCRs.xlsm"
Dim FileName As String
Dim ExcelWasAlreadyUp As Boolean

Unload UserForm1
UserForm2.Show

On Error Resume Next

Set XL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number = 0 Then 'attachment to an excel instance succeeded
    ExcelWasAlreadyUp = True
Else 'attachment to an excel instance failed, create one instead
    'Debug.Print Err.Number 'err.number 429 is expected here
    ExcelWasAlreadyUp = False
    Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

On Error GoTo 0
    Dim JArray() As Variant 'Jira data array
Dim ArrayCols As Integer

'==========================================================
With XL
    With .Workbooks
        .Open (ActivePresentation.Path & "/" & WB)
    End With
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .CalculateBeforeSave = False
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    '.Range("tbl_JiraKeysExtended").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    JArray = .Range("tbl_JiraKeysExtended") 'Reads in all Jira Base Ticket info instantly
    .Workbooks(WB).Close Savechanges:=False
End With
'==========================================================


'close Excel, but only if it wasn't active before script started
If ExcelWasAlreadyUp = False Then
    XL.Quit
    Set XL = Nothing
End If
```

Opening a file with an XL or WB object is apparently impossible.  This code is bulletproof in Windows...

Using an OLE object may be a way around this problem and I'll post again if it bears fruit.

edit: there's a bit of arcane info on Mac file access found here: https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/systemsbiology/staff/dyer/software/excelvbafileopen/

> In the 2016+ versions of Excel, VBA operates in a sandbox which means that explicit permission has to be granted if any files are to be opened. This is not required if the file has been identified with a appleScript 'fileopen dialog box. For other files this is granted using the GrantAccessToMultipleFiles method. This is wrapped in a method because if it is encountered in code prior to Excel 2016, or on a mac then it throws an untrappable error

```
Function grantFileAccess(filePermissionCandidates)
  grantFileAccess = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(filePermissionCandidates) 'returns true if access granted, false otherwise_
End Function
```

I don't personally have a Mac to test this on, please give feedback if this advances your script.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach to getting data shuttled over which uses OLE rather than COM.  Again, no Mac here to test with.  This code also integrates the relatively unknown VBA command for Mac that gets users to register files for permitted access to the Office sandbox.  The code is heavily commented to provide possible modifications needed to help get a script moving forward on a Mac.

The strategy behind this script is to add a 2nd slide to a presentation that otherwise has a single slide.  In this 2nd slide, add an OLE object in the form of an icon which serves as a tunnel to the spreadsheet from which data is being pulled.  When it's all imported, perform housekeeping by deleting the OLE object and the slide.  On Windows, this has the effect of properly terminating the excel.exe handler from Task Manager.

```
'starting with Office 2016 for Mac, Office is sandboxed and requires a one-time user-input to permit
'access to files that are outside the sandbox:
Dim FolderSeparator As String
#If MAC_OFFICE_VERSION >= 15 Then
    'Declare Variables 
    Dim fileAccessGranted As Boolean 
    Dim filePermissionCandidates

    'Create an array with file paths for the permissions that are needed. 
    FolderSeparator = "/"
    filePermissionCandidates = Array(ActivePresentation.Path & FolderSeparator & "RCRs.xlsm")

    'Request access from user. 
    fileAccessGranted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(filePermissionCandidates)
    'Returns true if access is granted; otherwise, false.
#Else
    FolderSeparator = "\"
#End If

Load UserForm2
UserForm2.Show
    
'***************
'Variable unused on my Windows instance since removing the manually-added OLE object closes
'down Excel instances properly. Mac implementation may require some additional Excel handler code:
Dim ExcelWasAlreadyUp As Boolean
'***************

Dim XL As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set XL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 'YMMV
'Set XL = GetObject(, "Object") 'YMMV
If Err.Number = 0 Then 'attachment to an excel instance succeeded
    ExcelWasAlreadyUp = True
Else 'attachment to an excel instance failed, create one instead
    'Debug.Print Err.Number 'err.number 429 is expected here
    ExcelWasAlreadyUp = False
    
    '*******************
    'using "Object" may be needed for Mac compatibility(?), but on Windows the "Object" keyword doesn't
    'allow the new Excel instance to close properly when the OLE object is deleted.  Pick one from here:
    Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'YMMV
    'Set XL = CreateObject("Object") 'YMMV
    '*******************
End If

On Error GoTo 0

Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout
Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout

Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(2, pptLayout)

Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes.AddOLEObject _
    (FileName:=ActivePresentation.Path + FolderSeparator + "rcrs.xlsx", _
    DisplayAsIcon:=True)

Dim objOLE As Object
Set objOLE = shp.OLEFormat.Object

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = objOLE.Sheets("JiraAll").Range("arr_JIRA")

Dim JArray() As Variant
JArray() = rng

shp.Delete
Set shp = Nothing

sld.Delete
Set sld = Nothing 'by this point any Windows Excel object *created* by PowerPoint will exit on its own
```

Note that user may be prompted by Excel to permit macro commands