# Create Excel spreadsheet from Word using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word, office-automation

I'm trying to create an Excel spreadsheet and populate it with data from Word, but I can't get VBA to follow through. It launches Excel, but then it errors out.

If I try early binding, such as with this code from the Microsoft Documentation, I get a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch on the `Set xlApp` line.

```
Sub test()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
End Sub
```

If I try late binding, I get a Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method on the `Set xlBook` line

```
Sub test()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlBook As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
End Sub
```

Many people throughout StackOverflow use variations of this successfully. I can't figure out why it doesn't work for me. One user on StackOverflow reported that the problem only persisted on their Mac. If it is a platform problem, is there a way to fix it so it will work on my Mac?

Comment: I'm not familiar with programming VBA with a Mac, but if you go to Tools > References ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4XN9.png)), do you have the "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library" ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diaKC.png))?

Comment: AFAIK the situation is still similar to what user user12750785 reported at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791807/word-for-mac-error-while-calling-excel-application-workbooks-open-runtime-erro/59831389#59831389, I.e. you do het an object back from the CreateObject but it"s a workbook object, not an application object.

Comment: Do you run the code on the MacOS? Have you tried running it on Windows? Does it work correctly?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, In their last paragraph, they mention that they need this to work on their Mac, so the MacOS tag should be added back, I believe.

Comment: Agree. It was not clear from the post whether the issue is specific to the MacOS or not. Added back.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, @jonsson. You figured it out for me. It needs the Parent with late binding.

Here is the amended code:

```
Sub test()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlBook As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlApp = xlApp.Parent
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows if you use the early-binding technology there is no need to use the `CreateObject` function in the code:

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Instead, you may use the `New` operator which creates a new Excel `Application` instance in the code:

```
Set xlApp = new Excel.Application
```

If you wanted to automate Microsoft Office Excel using early binding, you would add a reference to the "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library" from the `Project` | `References` dialog, and then declare your variable as being of the type `Excel.Application`. From then on, all calls made to your object variable would be early bound. Read more about late and early binding technologies in the [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients) article.

To use the late binding you must have Microsoft Excel installed on your computer and compile with `Option Strict Off` to allow late binding:

```
Sub TestLateBinding()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlBook As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ' Late bind an instance of an Excel workbook.
    xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    ' Late bind an instance of an Excel worksheet.
    xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
    xlSheet.Activate()
    ' Show the application.
    xlSheet.Application.Visible = True
    ' Place some text in the second row of the sheet.
    xlSheet.Cells(2, 2) = "This is column B row 2"
End Sub
```

You should use early-bound objects whenever possible, because they allow the compiler to make important optimizations that yield more efficient applications. Early-bound objects are significantly faster than late-bound objects and make your code easier to read and maintain by stating exactly what kind of objects are being used. Another advantage to early binding is that it enables useful features such as automatic code completion and Dynamic Help because the Visual Studio integrated development environment (IDE) can determine exactly what type of object you are working with as you edit the code. Early binding reduces the number and severity of run-time errors because it allows the compiler to report errors when a program is compiled.

On the MacOS you need to get the `Parent` property value of the created instance which represents the `Workbook` class, not `Application` like could be in case of Windows:

```
Dim childObjectCreated as Object
Set childObjectCreated = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlApp = childObjectCreated.Parent
```

Comment: That works on Windows and it "should" work on Mac, but it does not. IMO the answer required here is ideally "what makes the Windows code work properly on MacOs". Maybe you have that Answer!. Here, Set app = GetObject(,"Excel.Application") always returns error 429 (Excel running or not), and leaves app = Nothing. Using Set app = New Excel.Application returns error 430 and leaves app = Nothing. app = CreateObject("Excel.Application") returns an object ref. in app, and TypeName(app) is "WorkBook", and you can Set app = app.Parent to get the Application.