# Combine data from the same cell of multiple excel/csv files using a mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

I have 800 excel files but need to take one value from the same cell of each file and output them as a column in either a new excel file - does anyone know the quickest way to do this? I'm using a mac. Thanks!

Tried to move/copy in to sheets and then consolidate but not feasible for 800 pages - any help much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If they're all in the same folder, you can use `Dir` to loop through the files and get their name. Then use `Application.Workbooks.Open` and take the values from each workbook one by one.

Comment: Do the sheet that contain the cell  have the same name in all the files?

Answer (score 1):

if the sheets inside the files are the same try this, no need to open
EDIT: Change wildcards in Dir for an if in case this causes any trouble on MacOs (it Shouldn't but better safe than sorry)

```
Public Sub cellInFiles()
    Dim source As String: source = "c:\source\"
    Dim sourceSheetName As String: sourceSheetName = "Sheet1"
    Dim SourceCellAddress As String: SourceCellAddress = "$a$1"
    Dim fname As String
    
    fname = Dir(source)
    ix = 1
    While fname <> ""
        If fname Like "*.xl*" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ix, 1).Formula = "='" & source & "[" & fname & "]" & sourceSheetName & "'!" & SourceCellAddress
            ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:=source & fname, Type:=xlExcelLinks
            ix = ix + 1
        End If
        fname = Dir()
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: That will put a formula for every excel workbook into the sheet - and while you don't have to "open" the file, Excel will do it in the background any time when the sheet is recalculated. Could be *very* slow. And note that on a Mac, `Dir` doesn't work with wildcards, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045474/dir-function-not-working-in-mac-excel-2011-vba

Comment: @FunThomas , The is no recalculation, see the link is broken in the next line, so the value is taken from the file and at the next line only the value stay (no the formula with the link.  For sure this is more faster than opening the file manually.

Comment: @FunThomas, according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function), dir supports wildcards in macOs  "In Microsoft Windows and macOS, Dir supports the use of multiple character (*) and single character (?) wildcards to specify multiple files.".

Comment: Haven't seen that you break the links - good idea (have you tested that at this point the value is already there?). With the `Dir`, I cannot say anything because I have no Mac, it's just that I remembered that there are issues with it and found the question I linked.

Comment: @FunThomas, It is tested and linking and breaking the link is fast and works flawlessly. Event though documentation says there is no problem with wildcards I changed the code to eliminate the wildcards